# Parse JSON MSG in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a json MSG into a python dict.

For reference, the message is received from the Things Network with the python MQTT handler.

Here is the format I am receiving when I print the object

```
msg = MSG(variable_group=MSG(data0=0, data1=0, data2=0), variable2='name', variable3='num')
```

In its default state, I can access individual fields by msg.variable2 for example which provides 'name' but does not provide the variable name itself.

This is fine for a scenario in which I hardcode everything into my system, but I would like it to be a bit more adaptable and create new entries for variables as they come in.

Is there any way to parse this in such a way that I get both the data and the variable name?

Thanks!

EDIT:

From the input above, I would like to get a python dict containing the variable name and data.

```
dict = 
{
variable_group : MSG(data0=0, data1=0, data2=0),
variable2 : 'name',
variable3 : 'num'
}
```

Currently, I can access the data via a for loop and can print the variable names if I print the entire structure, but cannot access the variable names through a looping mechanism

EDIT 2:

After doing some digging on the wrapper found the following:

```
def _json_object_hook(d):
    return namedtuple("MSG", d.keys())(*d.values())


def json2obj(data):
    return json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook)
```

Where the input shown above is created by passing it as 'data' to json2obj.

I am still unsure how to get a dict out of this format, haven't used object_hooks before.

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: From the input above, the desired output would be a python dict (or other structure) formatted as {variable_group : MSG(data.....), variable2 : 'name', variable3 : 'num'

Comment: In short you want to access like `msg.name`? and name in the not the key in the dictionary but value right?

Comment: No, updated above. I want to be able to access the variable names which I cannot do as they are formatted in the input. Accessing data is currently not a problem

Comment: Have you tried `msg.__dict__`

Comment: Just tried msg.__dict__, not an attribute of the "MSG" object.

Comment: can you provide the link to that MSG repository?

Comment: I am using the ttn library for LoraWan comms. Python SDK here https://github.com/TheThingsNetwork/python-app-sdk

Comment: The message is created in the ttnmqtt.py under the MQTT client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From discussion in the comments below, it appears that the MSG object is a namedtuple created on the fly out of the json object.

In a case like that you can get the fields by looking at the `_fields` of the object.  You can dict-ify a namedtuple like this

```
def nt_to_dict(nt):
     return {field, getattr(nt, field) for field in nt._fields}
```

or you could just inspect the object by trolling `_fields` in code and using `getattr` as needed

Comment: It is not a regular json blob as far as I can tell. I have tried both loads and load without a successful conversion. It is referred to in the errors as a 'MSG' object

Comment: you could brute force reflection by looking at the `__dict__` of the MSG object.

Comment: Already tried that from a response in the comments above. Spits back that __dict__ is not an attribute of the MSG object

Comment: ouch, an old style class? Or some kind of C wrapper object?

Comment: Not 100% sure. Its definitely a json format. Best I can find is this line obj = json2obj(j_msg) from inside the sdk

Comment: After doing a bit more digging on that wrapper, found that the json2obj is is a util function I missed. It does: json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook) where _json_object_hook returns namedtuple("MSG", d.keys())(*d.values())... Any idea how to perform that in reverse?

Comment: Had to fiddle with it a bit more to account for the nested namedtuples, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: [`namedtuple._asdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict), as in `def nt_to_dict(nt): return dict(nt._asdict())`